# Defining Android tags in layout xml doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to put some initial data about views in tags with the layout xml in android studio, but whenever I try to get the tags in the program, it returns null.
Here is my xml:

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<tag
    android:id="@+id/role"
    android:value="@string/titleBar"/>
(all of the views...)
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

And I'm trying to get the value of the tag with:

```java
ViewGroup mainLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
for (int i = 0; i < mainLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(mainLayout.getChildAt(i).getTag(R.id.role));
}
```

I used  to put the LinearLayout in my main layout.

Comment: It's possible something like that syntax exists, but I do not recall ever seeing anyone use it. You can use [an `android:tag` attribute](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View?hl=en#android:tag), though that too is uncommon.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just tried that, and I used getTag() instead of getTag(R.id.role). It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured out what my issue is. It has nothing to do with the tags. My issue is that getChildCount() and getChildAt() only work with views, not included layouts. Because I was including the LinearLayout in a separate main layout, I could not actually find it by iterating through the layout children as shown in my code. I just referenced it with a findViewById(), and it worked fine!